# SSIS quotable fields

Tags: ssis, field, dts

I have these fields and I need to choose which of them are going to be quotables in order to be exported in flat file in SSI. (DTS used to have this option)

field1,field2,field3

field1, field3 = quotables

"field1",field2,"field3"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open the editor of your Flat File Connection in your Connection Manager.
2. In the **General** section, set the *Text qualifier:* property to a double quote (").
3. Click the **Advanced** section from the left hand menu.
4. For each column, set the *TextQualified* property to True or False as needed. By default, all columns are treated as strings and the *TextQualified* property is set to True.